# if (lock) wait else lock=1 CS lock=0

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, locking

Consider this possible implementation of a synchronization mechanism, the goal being that only one thread is in the critical section (CS) at a time:

```
if (lock)
      wait
else
     lock=1
      CS
     lock=0
```

Will this work for a multiprocessor system?

Comment: @H2CO3 Context easy to infer if you know the subject, though. I've edited it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This won't even work on a single-processor system. Suppose you have two threads doing this. They could be scheduled this way:

```
thread1                     thread2
if (lock) /*false*/
                            if (lock) /*false*/
                            lock=1
lock=1
/*CS*/
                            /*CS*/
/*CS continues*/
                            /*CS continues*/
                            lock=0
lock=0
```

You can't implement a lock this way. One of the ways to implement a lock is with a processor instructions that **atomically** checks the current value of the variable *and* assigns to it, such as [test-and-set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set). (There are many other possible ways, different CPUs provide different methods and sometimes more than one.)

Comment: Can you tell a way in which we can rectify this code for a uni-processor system? test-and-set will only make it work for multiprocessor systems, right?

Comment: @Gaurav Test-and-set is a building block for a [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock), a lock implementations which is suitable for locks that are taken for a very short time. You need to ensure that the other threads can run while a thread is doing `wait`. There is little use for a spinlock on a single-processor system except as a building block for a mutex with a wait queue, but it works regardless of the number of processors.